# Incorrect output texture on quad

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, freetype

I'm trying to display the text in my application using freetype. At first I thought that this built-in function (which would be quite natural for the library intended to draw the text). But there was only a function to display the symbol.Then I decided to take the characters one by one into a texture. But here again I was disappointed: all guides one texture uses a single image (probably glTexSubImage2D can help me?).Now I put a symbol on the texture and texture to opengl element.Here's my code (it's quite messy, but now I'm just trying to understand how it works):

```
//init:

    if (FT_Init_FreeType(&ft)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not init freetype library\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if (FT_New_Face(ft, fontfilename, 0, &face)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open font %s\n", fontfilename);
        return 0;
    }
    FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, 48);    FT_GlyphSlot g = face->glyph;
```

and from display():

```
 void display()
 {
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glClearColor(1.0 ,1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity();//load identity matrix
std::string s = "QWERTYOG0l  ";

for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++){
    FT_Load_Char( face, s[i], FT_LOAD_RENDER );
    FT_GlyphSlot g = face->glyph;
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR); // Linear Filtering
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR); // Linear Filtering
    //glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    gluBuild2DMipmaps( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
          GL_RED, 
          g->bitmap.width, 
          g->bitmap.rows, 
          GL_RED, 
          GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
          g->bitmap.buffer );
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
      glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);glVertex3f(0.1f*i-0.1,0.07f,0.0f); //top left
      glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);glVertex3f(0.1f*i,0.07f,0.0f); //top right
      glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);glVertex3f(0.1f*i,-0.07f,0.0f); // bottom right
      glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);glVertex3f(0.1f*i-0.1,-0.07f,0.0f); //bottom left
    glEnd();
}
```

[image: code result]

As you can see the "O" and "T" is correct (if I change bottom left and top right corners of texture it will be absolutely correct). But other symbols seems like shifted (for example "E" is shifted at left from top to bottom).

The full code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H


FT_Library ft;
FT_Face face;
const char *fontfilename = "LucidaTypewriterBold.ttf";
GLuint      texture[10];  

GLint uniform_mytexture;
int setup() { 
    if (FT_Init_FreeType(&ft)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not init freetype library\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if (FT_New_Face(ft, fontfilename, 0, &face)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open font %s\n", fontfilename);
        return 0;
    }
    FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, 48);
    FT_Load_Char( face, 'O', FT_LOAD_RENDER );
    FT_GlyphSlot g = face->glyph;

    glGenTextures(1, &texture[0]);    // Create The Texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR); // Linear Filtering
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR); // Linear Filtering
    //glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D,  GL_RGBA, g->bitmap.width, g->bitmap.rows,  GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, g->bitmap.buffer);
    return 1;
 }
void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(1.0 ,1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();//load identity matrix
    std::string s = "QWERTYOG0l  ";

    for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++){
        FT_Load_Char( face, s[i], FT_LOAD_RENDER );
        FT_GlyphSlot g = face->glyph;
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR); // Linear Filtering
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR); // Linear Filtering
        //glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
        gluBuild2DMipmaps( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
              GL_RED, 
              g->bitmap.width, 
              g->bitmap.rows, 
              GL_RED, 
              GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
              g->bitmap.buffer );
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
          glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);glVertex3f(0.1f*i-0.1,0.07f,0.0f); //top left
          glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);glVertex3f(0.1f*i,0.07f,0.0f); //top right
          glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);glVertex3f(0.1f*i,-0.07f,0.0f); // bottom right
          glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);glVertex3f(0.1f*i-0.1,-0.07f,0.0f); //bottom left
        glEnd();
    }

    //glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    //glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);               // Select Our Texture

 // glUniform1i(uniform_mytexture, /*GL_TEXTURE*/0);
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
void TimerFunction(int value)
{


}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
       glutInit(&argc, argv);
       glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE);
       glutInitWindowSize(800,600);
       glutCreateWindow("Hello World");
        //glutTimerFunc(30, TimerFunction, 1);
       glewInit();
       glEnable (GL_TEXTURE_2D);

       setup();
       glutDisplayFunc(display);

       glutMainLoop();

       return 0;
}
```

Comment: Strange behaviour. What happens if you put only "Q" letter in your string? Is it as distorted as previously? Also if you switch places of "T" and "Q" letters, would "T" still be displayed properly and "Q" distorted?

Comment: Why are you passing `GL_RED` to `gluBuild2DMipmaps()` instead of `GLU_RED`?  Same with `GL_RGBA`.

Comment: genpfault, because i can't find `GLU_RED`.I never heard of this constant.
Mosquito, position of letters does not affect the drawing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been looking into this for a bit, and while this answer is possibly incomplete, maybe it can help you figure it out.

### Preliminary Note

Before I get to what I have found, I need to point out a problem with your texture coordinates.  You have this:

```
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);glVertex3f(0.1f*i-0.1,0.07f,0.0f); //top left
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);glVertex3f(0.1f*i,0.07f,0.0f); //top right
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);glVertex3f(0.1f*i,-0.07f,0.0f); // bottom right
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);glVertex3f(0.1f*i-0.1,-0.07f,0.0f); //bottom left
```

when it should look like this:

```
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);glVertex3f(0.1f*i-0.1,0.07f,0.0f); //top left
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);glVertex3f(0.1f*i,0.07f,0.0f); //top right
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);glVertex3f(0.1f*i,-0.07f,0.0f); // bottom right
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);glVertex3f(0.1f*i-0.1,-0.07f,0.0f); //bottom left
```

note how the top left corresponds to 0, 0 in texture coordinates, and 1, 1 corresponds to the bottom right.  This is because (kind of guessing here) freetype puts treats the top left as its origin.

### The Stuff That May Help

Freetype will not generate a bitmap whose dimensions are necessarily power-of-two, which is often required for mipmapping (see: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/7929 ).

So if you want to test this (**note: do not actually use this in your code; this is only for illustration**) you can replace your `gluBuild2DMipmaps` call in `display` with the following (be sure to `#include <cstring>`:

```
int pitch = g->bitmap.pitch;
if (pitch < 0) {
    pitch = -pitch;
}

unsigned char data[4096] = {0};
for (int row = 0; row < g->bitmap.rows; ++row) {
    std::memcpy(data + 64 * row, g->bitmap.buffer + pitch * row, pitch);
}

gluBuild2DMipmaps(
    GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
    GL_RGBA, 
    64, 
    64, 
    GL_RED, 
    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
    data
);
```

What it does is copy the bitmap buffer to the upper left corner of a different 64x64-byte buffer, and then builds the mipmaps from that.  This is the result:

[image: result]

### Further Notes

My illustration code is bad because it copies the bitmap data for each glyph every redraw, and it does not take into account the actual size of the bitmap buffer, or if pitch is greater than 64.  You also probably do not want to be (re)generating your mipmaps every redraw, either, but if you are just trying to learn how to get words into OpenGL do not worry about it :)

Edit: I had to use a different font than you because I do not have yours.

Comment: Many thanks for the excellent response. The problem was not in glyph size, but with power of two it looks really better. And about angle of letters - yes it was my stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1):

As tecu said, the correct solution is using textures with power of two size.

Also before that answer i found another solution:
`glPixelStorei( GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1 );` before `gluBuild2DMipmaps`. But here you get more problems like gray border around texture.

For those who are asking similar goals I want to share my experience:

**Make black on a transparent background:**

```
GLfloat swizzleMask[] = { 0,0,0, GL_RED}; 
glTexParameterfv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_RGBA, swizzleMask);
```

**UPD** there is a more simple and obvious solution withput using an OpenGL extension.
        `gluBuild2DMipmaps( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
          GL_ALPHA, 
          g->bitmap.width, 
          g->bitmap.rows, 
          GL_RGBA, 
          GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
          g->bitmap.buffer )`

**Connect all the letters in a single texture**

I think that this is better for perfomance, but not sure that I change the right way.

```
    if(text[i] == ' ') left += 20; else
    for (int row = 0; row < g->bitmap.rows; ++row) {
        std::memcpy(data + left + 64*(strSize*(row + 64 -  g->bitmap_top))
            , g->bitmap.buffer + pitch * row, pitch);
    }
    left += g->advance.x >> 6;
```

It will better if you calculate width and height (and round to power of two) before connecting in data array.

If you want **kerning** you should write its own slower implementation of memcpy, where you will add (not fully change) the value and check exceeding of `UCHAR_MAX`.

My final result: [image]