# Indexing pixels in a monochrome FreeType glyph buffer

Tags: freetype

I want to translate a monochrome FreeType glyph to an RGBA unsigned byte OpenGL texture.  The colour of the texture at pixel (x, y) would be (255, 255, alpha), where

```
alpha = glyph->bitmap.buffer[pixelIndex(x, y)] * 255
```

I load my glyph using

```
FT_Load_Char(face, glyphChar, FT_LOAD_RENDER | FT_LOAD_MONOCHROME | FT_LOAD_TARGET_MONO)
```

The target texture has dimensions of `glyph->bitmap.width * glyph->bitmap.rows`.  I've been able to index a greyscale glyph (loaded using just `FT_Load_Char(face, glyphChar, FT_LOAD_RENDER)`) with

```
glyph->bitmap.buffer[(glyph->bitmap.width * y) + x]
```

This does not appear work on a monochrome buffer though and the characters in my final texture are scrambled.

What is the correct way to get the value of pixel (x, y) in a monochrome glyph buffer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [this thread I started on Gamedev.net](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/638764-indexing-pixels-in-monochrome-freetype-glyph/), I've come up with the following function to get the filled/empty state of the pixel at (x, y):

```
bool glyphBit(const FT_GlyphSlot &glyph, const int x, const int y)
{
    int pitch = abs(glyph->bitmap.pitch);
    unsigned char *row = &glyph->bitmap.buffer[pitch * y];
    char cValue = row[x >> 3];

    return (cValue & (128 >> (x & 7))) != 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similiar question some time ago. So I would to try help you.

> The target texture has dimensions of `glyph->bitmap.width * glyph->bitmap.rows`

This is very specific dimension for OpenGl. Would be better if you round this to power of two.

In common way you make cycle where you get every glyph. Then cycle for every row from 0 to `glyph->bitmap.rows`. Then cycle for every byte (`unsigned char`) in row from 0 to `glyph->pitch`. Where you get byte by handling `glyph->bitmap.buffer[pitch * row + i]` (i is index of inner cycle and row is index of outer). For example:

```
if(s[i] == ' ') left += 20; else
    for (int row = 0; row < g->bitmap.rows; ++row) {
             if(kerning)
            for(int b = 0; b < pitch; b++){
                if(data[left + 64*(strSize*(row + 64 -  g->bitmap_top)) + b] + g->bitmap.buffer[pitch * row + b] < UCHAR_MAX)
                    data[left + 64*(strSize*(row + 64 -  g->bitmap_top)) + b] += g->bitmap.buffer[pitch * row + b];
                else
                    data[left + 64*(strSize*(row + 64 -  g->bitmap_top)) + b] = UCHAR_MAX;
            } else
        std::memcpy(data + left + 64*(strSize*(row + 64 -  g->bitmap_top)) , g->bitmap.buffer + pitch * row, pitch);
    }
    left += g->advance.x >> 6;
```

This code is relevant to an 8-bit bitmap (standart `FT_Load_Char(face, glyphChar, FT_LOAD_RENDER)`).
Now I tried to use the monochrome flag and it caused me trouble. So my answer is not a solution to your problem. If you just want to display the letter then you should see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800667/incorrect-output-texture-on-quad).

Answer (score 0):

The following Python function unpacks a `FT_LOAD_TARGET_MONO` glyph bitmap into a more convenient representation where each byte in the buffer maps to one pixel.

I've got some more info on monochrome font rendering with Python and FreeType plus additional example code on my blog: http://dbader.org/blog/monochrome-font-rendering-with-freetype-and-python

```py
def unpack_mono_bitmap(bitmap):
    """
    Unpack a freetype FT_LOAD_TARGET_MONO glyph bitmap into a bytearray where each
    pixel is represented by a single byte.
    """
    # Allocate a bytearray of sufficient size to hold the glyph bitmap.
    data = bytearray(bitmap.rows * bitmap.width)

    # Iterate over every byte in the glyph bitmap. Note that we're not
    # iterating over every pixel in the resulting unpacked bitmap --
    # we're iterating over the packed bytes in the input bitmap.
    for y in range(bitmap.rows):
      for byte_index in range(bitmap.pitch):

        # Read the byte that contains the packed pixel data.
        byte_value = bitmap.buffer[y * bitmap.pitch + byte_index]

        # We've processed this many bits (=pixels) so far. This determines
        # where we'll read the next batch of pixels from.
        num_bits_done = byte_index * 8

        # Pre-compute where to write the pixels that we're going
        # to unpack from the current byte in the glyph bitmap.
        rowstart = y * bitmap.width + byte_index * 8

        # Iterate over every bit (=pixel) that's still a part of the
        # output bitmap. Sometimes we're only unpacking a fraction of a byte
        # because glyphs may not always fit on a byte boundary. So we make sure
        # to stop if we unpack past the current row of pixels.
        for bit_index in range(min(8, bitmap.width - num_bits_done)):

          # Unpack the next pixel from the current glyph byte.
          bit = byte_value & (1 << (7 - bit_index))

          # Write the pixel to the output bytearray. We ensure that `off`
          # pixels have a value of 0 and `on` pixels have a value of 1.
          data[rowstart + bit_index] = 1 if bit else 0

    return data
```