# How to access pixel's state in monochrome bitmap using freetype2

Tags: c++, freetype

Here is a code snippet:

```
wchar_t wc=L"か";
FT_UInt glyph_index = FT_Get_Char_Index(face, wc);
FT_Load_Glyph(face, glyph_index, FT_LOAD_DEFAULT);
if(face->glyph->format !=ft_glyph_format_bitmap)
{
    FT_Render_Glyph(face->glyph, FT_RENDER_MODE_MONO);
}
FT_GlyphSlot slot = face->glyph;
int rows = slot->bitmap.rows;
int cols = slot->bitmap.width; 
for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) 
{
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) 
    {
        int off  = i * slot->bitmap.pitch + j / 8;
        if (slot->bitmap.buffer[off] & (0xC0 >> (j % 8))) 
        {
              //do something if above condition met
        }
}
```

So, how to understand the variable `off` and condition `slot->bitmap.buffer[off] & (0x80 >> (j % 8))`?

In effect, similar case can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800827/indexing-pixels-in-a-monochrome-freetype-glyph-buffer?answertab=votes#tab-top). A function was defined as follows:

```
bool glyphBit(const FT_GlyphSlot &glyph, const int x, const int y)
{
    int pitch = abs(glyph->bitmap.pitch);
    unsigned char *row = &glyph->bitmap.buffer[pitch * y];
    char cValue = row[x >> 3];

    return (cValue & (128 >> (x & 7))) != 0;
}
```

It is basically equivalent to above snippet, so I believe there exists a pixel indexing criteria, but I cannot figure it out even with the [official document](https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/glyphs/glyphs-7.html#section-3) of freetype2, who can help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs, `FT_RENDER_MODE_MONO` means you're rendering a monochrome bitmap using a **one-bit-per-pixel** format. This means that each byte of the bitmap you've just rendered two represents one row and 8 columns.  In order to check if a pixel in column j is set in the bitmap, you must check the jth bit in a row.

`off` should now make more sense... `i * slot->bitmap.pitch + j / 8` gets the offset of the *byte* in which your pixel lies. That's why it only increments by 1 for every 8 columns. You can't do memory reads and writes with offsets specified in bits, after all.

The test code you've provided, however, look like bit might be buggy. The second version uses `128`, which has the binary representation of `10000000`. The `>> (x & 7)` gets you each successive bit in turn, which can then be bitwise-anded with the byte in which the pixel lies to check if the pixel is actually turned on. The first version of your code has 0xC0 instead, which has bitwise representation `11000000`, and so the test isn't actually doing what you want at all (it is checking if the *j* th and *j+1* th pixels are set, unless `j % 8` is `7`)

Comment: In a monochrome bitmap, each byte has 8 pixels in it. A row is represented by multiple bytes, dependent on the width of the actual image. Let's say it were 10 pixels for example. Then two bytes represent a row and typically the trailing bits of the second byte will be unset (0). Let's go further and say the height of the image was 2 (to make this easy) and just so my point is clear let's say the image is all white. In 2D the array would look like: `{{0xff, 0xc0}, {0xff, 0xc0}}`.

Comment: the key point I overlooked is "can't do memory reads and writes with offsets specified in bits". So `slot->bitmap.buffer[off]` will access the value that starts from `off`with length of a byte, then step a byte to next `off` and so on. Thanks for your help:)